# XHTML Strict 1.0 .. unlimited errors

Tags: xhtml

i've checked my XHTML Strict 1.0 code and i faced a lot of errors the validator : validator.w3.org please can you help me fixing errors

code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html
PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en"> <head>

    <title>  my trip around the US on my very own Segway </title>
 </head>

  <body>
    <h1> Segway'n USA </h1>

    <p>

      Documenting my trip around the US on my
very own Segway
    </p>

    <h2> August 20, 2005 </h2>

    <img src="images/segway2.jpg"/ alt="segway"/>

    <p>
      Well I made it 1200 miles already, and I passed
       through some interesting places on the way:
   </p>

   <ol> <!-- ordered list -->
<li>Walla Walla, WA</li>
<li>Magic City, ID</li>
<li>Bountiful, UT</li>
<li>Last Chance, CO</li>
<li>Why, AZ</li>
<li>Truth or Consequences, NM</li>
    </ol>

    <h2> July 14, 2005 </h2>

    <p>
      I saw some Burma Shave style signs on the side of the
       road today :
    </p>

    <blockquote>
Passing cars,
When you can't see, May get you,
A glimpse,
Of eternity.
    </blockquote>
    <p>
      I definitely won't be passing any cars.
    </p>

    <h2> June 2, 2005 </h2>

    <img src="images/segway1.jpg"/ alt="segway">

    <p>
      My frst day of the trip! I can't believe I fnally got
       everything packed and ready to go. Because I'm on a Segway,
       I wasn't able to bring a whole lot with me: cellphone, iPod,
       digital camera, and a protein bar. Just the essentials. As
       Lao Tzu would have said, <q>A journey of a thousand miles begins
       with one Segway</q>
    </p>

  </body>

  </html>
```

full code link : http://pastebin.com/L95bt2Yu

thanks guys

Comment: Could you be more lazy? "unlimited errors". 11 errors found on validation. Most of which on the same line. All errors are followed with a very clear reason for the failure and the possible fix ups. I made your markup valid with just 6 fixes, none of which but one required any particular effort.

Comment: Take some time going through the errors and trying to fix them depending on what message is given. This isn't a "fix your code" site. You can try [Stack Exchange's Code Review site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but that likely wouldn't be much help for XHTML.

Comment: okey but no need to decrasing my reputation , am beginner in this site and need some help ;-( Thanks anyway

Comment: Your reputation can't drop below 1 anyway, so don't worry. But tell me, does this page show up the way you want in your browser? If so, it isn't  an actual XHTML document, and there's no need to insist upon XHTML content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the validator first (use the XML parser first) and don't use old versions of XHTML. You should use HTML5 for HTML and XHTML for the XML parser which will catch about 80% of rendering errors right off the bat and streamline your development. So that means use XHTML5 for the best of both worlds. To use HTML5 you need to use the HTML5 elements. To use the XML parser you need to serve the page as `application/xhtml+xml`. Locally you need to save a file with a `.xhtml` extension. Do not let the overwhelming negative attitude towards XHTML undermine the usefulness of the XML parser, the best use the best tools and ignore the masses when they're wrong. As long as you use it in conjunction with HTML5 then you're doing the most you can do and that puts you far ahead of most people.

For servers you need to do content negotiation. When you get to PHP use the following *before* you send non-header data (e.g. *any* HTML/`echo`):

```
if (stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'],'application/xhtml+xml'))
{
 header('Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml');
}
```

Until you get to that point use the a program like [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) to determine how code is different if for full pages until you're able to narrow it down.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>XHTML5 Example</title>
<meta name="description" content="Manage domain accounts." />
<meta name="keywords" content="example" />
<meta name="language" content="en" />
<meta name="robots" content="noarchive, noindex, nofollow" />
<base href="https://localhost/" />
<link href="blog/rss/" rel="alternate" title="Blog RSS Feed" type="application/rss+xml" />
<link href="favicon.ico" rel="icon" />
<script defer="defer" src="scripts/index.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>

<h1><span>Example Header, use h1 element only once per page</span></h1>
<main>
 <p>Example paragraph.</p>

<ol>
 <li><span>Bullet One</span></li>
 <li><span>Bullet Two</span></li>
 <li><span>Bullet Three</span></li>
</ol>

<ul>
 <li><span>Bullet</span></li>
 <li><span>Bullet</span></li>
 <li><span>Bullet</span></li>
</ul>

<blockquote>
 <p>The <code>blockquote</code> element may contain block-level elements.
 The <code>q</code> element may only contain inline elements.</p>
</blockquote>
</main>

<aside>
<img alt="Alternative text displayed only if image does not load" src="example.png" />
</aside>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you for your support , you're awesome , but am beginner in HTML and i want to study the standards first , i think you're talking about some thing that is hard to do for me , or maybe it's difficullt to understand , thank you anyway

Comment: Just think of the parsers as which bucket you want to carry water in. XML parser is stricter so there is much less leakage. If you want XHTML/CSS/JavaScript to go by look at my site in my profile, it's as high-quality as code can get and it lets me do things others simply can't. :-)